# When is it appropriate to calculate the p-value?

Tags: statistics, p-value

I seem to be confused on what is the utility of calculating the p-value.

Let's say for the sake of argument, that I'm doing hypothesis testing on a normal distribution with a known $\mu$ and known $\sigma$. We have the sample therefore we also computed the sample mean.

I would therefore compute my test statistic: $$ \dfrac{\overline X - \mu}{\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}$$

and see if it falls within the area between  $Z_{-\alpha/2}$ and $Z_{\alpha/2}$.
If it doesn't we reject the null hypothesis.

Now what is the point of calculating the p-value if we can do this. When is it appropriate to use the p-value instead for accepting or rejecting the null hypothesis.

Comment: if the p value is below a certain threshold, say 0.05, there is reasonable suspicion to reject the null hypothesis; the null hypothesis being that the true value of the mean is what was expected

Comment: this is not what I'm asking. I want to know why would you ever need the p-value if you can do what I did above.

Comment: you would need the p value to find that $Z_{-\alpha/2}$ and $Z_{\alpha/2}$

Comment: You wouldn't. you would just have to know with what confidence we want to test the hypothesis

Comment: Did you mean unknown $\mu$? In that case a decision based on the p-value is just an alternative to a test where you reject the null if the observed value of the test statistic is greater/less than some cut-off value like $z_{\alpha/2}$.